# SQL query from relations

Tags: sql

If I have these relations:

- Races(**raceId**, description)
- Results(***horseName*, *raceId***, finishTime, prizeMoney)
- Horses(**horseName**, *motherName*, *fatherName*)
- Owners(***personName, horseName***)
- Persons(**personName**)

and I want to find the name of all owners that own horses who have not participated in a race.

This is my solution:

```
select personName
from Owners
where horseName not in (select horseName from Results);
```

however according to the answer sheet they do like this:

```
select distinct personName
from Owners natural join Horses
left outer join Results on Horses.horseName = Results.horseName
where prizeMoney is null;
```

Comment: Answer sheet? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @Jay Obviously, and there's nothing wrong with that.  The answer sheet answer looks to be too busy, honestly.  Your answer looks fine.  They have a `Join` to `Horses` which isn't needed, and the `Left Outer Join ... Where Null` does the same thing as your `Not In`.  Your answer is more efficient, though functionally equivalent.  The only thing I might add is a `Distinct` so that you don't get duplicates.

Comment: THe left join syntax will be more effiecient than the where not in() format (especially if this is MySQL)...but the way they have that left join written makes yours considerably better. you'd want to eliminate the 'natural' join (no clue why that is in there since you can go owners to results without horses) and assume that null prize money = didn't race.

Comment: @Twelfth The `Where PrizeMoney Is Null` appears to be their `Null` check for the right side.  Why they picked that instead of `HorseName`, which is in the `On` clause, is beyond me.

Comment: Why so much discussion of a question that hasn't even asked a question?

Comment: @siyual - thats why I said that assumption. I'm assuming that a horse that came in dead last didn't receive prize money and if no prize money means the prizemoney is null, then this query will functionally return 'all horses that have no won money in a race', which isn't what he is going for. If it holds 0 instead of null for prizemoney, then it's not an issue. results.horsename is null --probably a better way of doing this to account for prizemoney nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours is fine. Theirs answer is bad in a whole number of ways - doing a natural join is needless and bad for performance, among other things.

You might like to include the distinct, however, as the query you've written can (and likely will) result in the same owner being returned multiple times (once for each horse they own that hasn't run a race).

Comment: A natural join joins two tables based on columns of the same name. So it's basically doing an inner join between OWNERS and HORSES on HORSENAME. That is an extra step not needed to solve the given problem, however it is not as bad as doing a CROSS JOIN (the absence of join conditions entirely, ie. to produce a cartesian product).

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Ooooh, my bad. I use SQL Server which has no natural joins, and I misread when I was reading up on it... I'll fix my answer